# Why does RadAsyncUpload not upload the file?

Tags: .net, telerik

I am switching some code from RadUpload to RadAsyncUpload in order to prevent a file size over 250MB etc.

When I switch the code back to RadUpload the file does Upload to the \Upload folder - but this is not occuring with RadAsyncUpload.

I have set most if not of the OnClient events as shown in the code, but the only one firing is `OnClientFileUploaded` However the file does not end up in the `TargetFolder`

What can be done to trouble-shoot the File not actually uploading? How can it be made to work?

JavaScript

```
    function OnClientFileUploadFailed(sender, args) {
    alert("OnClientFileUploadFailed");
    alert(args.get_message());
}
function OnClientValidationFailed(sender, args) {
    alert("OnClientValidationFailed");
    //alert(args.get_message());
}
function OnClientFileDropped(sender, args) {
    alert("OnClientFileDropped");
    //alert(args.get_message());
}
function OnClientFileUploaded(sender, args) {
    alert("OnClientFileUploaded");
    //alert(args.get_message());
}
function OnClientFileUploadRemoved(sender, args) {
    alert("OnClientFileUploadRemoved");
    //alert(args.get_message());
}
```

.ASPX

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload 
    runat="server"
    ID="fuUploadFile"
    MaxFileSize="262144000"
    ControlObjectsVisibility="None" 
    OnClientFileUploadFailed="OnClientFileUploadFailed" 
    OnClientValidationFailed="OnClientValidationFailed" 
    OnClientFileDropped="OnClientFileDropped" 
    OnClientFileUploaded="OnClientFileUploaded" 
    OnClientFileUploadRemoved="OnClientFileUploadRemoved" 
    InputSize="50"
    TargetFolder="\Upload"
    AllowedFileExtensions=".wav,.mp3,.mpeg,.mpg,.wmv,.avi,.mp4" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you still need to do a page PostBack if you want to automatically copy the file to the Target folder.